# How to break this while loop in apache poi getStringCellValue loop

Tags: java, while-loop, apache-poi

My code has generated the search string `veri_tipi` in excel to find and get text values that match. But if the column has similar values, lets say my string is `"aaaa"` and the cell has `aaaa bbbbb`, it replaces the last found result.

What I need, if I understand correctly, is to break the while loop. Can someone help me figure out what to do after this?

```
if (cell.getStringCellValue().equals(veri_Tipi)){ 

                            CellReference nextCellAdress = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(),cell.getColumnIndex()+2);

                            Row next_Cell_Row = sheet.getRow(nextCellAdress.getRow());
                            Cell next_Cell = next_Cell_Row.getCell(nextCellAdress.getCol());

while(rowIterator.hasNext() ) {


       Row row = rowIterator.next();

        //For each row, iterate through each columns

       Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();



        while(cellIterator.hasNext()){

            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
               //     System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                   // System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
              if (cell.getStringCellValue().equals(veri_Tipi)){ 

                                CellReference nextCellAdress = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(),cell.getColumnIndex()+2);

                                Row next_Cell_Row = sheet.getRow(nextCellAdress.getRow());
                                Cell next_Cell = next_Cell_Row.getCell(nextCellAdress.getCol());



                switch(next_Cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:

                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:

                     break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

                    bilancoVeriExcel =next_Cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    String strDouble = String.valueOf((bilancoVeriExcel));

                    myList_DoubleHash.add(strDouble);
                    myListHash.add(cell.getStringCellValue());

                    System.out.print(myListHash+"\n");
                    System.out.print(myList_DoubleHash+"\n");
                    System.out.print(myList_DoubleHash.size()+"\n");

                    break;
                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:

                    break;

                                }

                                } 

            }

                  }

        }
```

Comment: Note : The logic of code to find, string, then move 2nd next cell in the row and get the value

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `while(cellIterator.hasNext())`, you should use:

```
for (int cellNo = 0; cellNo < row.getLastCellNum(); cellNo++){

    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could actually use a label. Example

```
myLoop:
while( boolean ) {

    if( true ) {

        break myLoop;

    }

}
```